# the delayed 13.15 from Hereford

Tags: meaning

> The train just arrived at platform six is **the delayed 13.15 from
> Hereford**.

[Swan: *Practical English Usage*, Oxford] (emphasis mine)

**Question:** Which of the following is correct?

(1) The train departed from Hereford at 13.15.

(2) The train arrived at the platform at 13.15.

(3) The train arrived at the platform later than at 13.15.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to an inbound train as “the 13.15 from Hereford” means that it was scheduled to arrive at 13.15. So if it was delayed, then option 3.